# Insert static library (.a) with Application's executable binary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

Use-Case :

1. Have a pre-built iOS executable app (.iPa of simulator/device).
2. Have pre-built static library.
3. Is it possible to merge / insert static Library from step-2 into iOS
   executable in step-1 and later generate a new executable (using
   command line) which now has a static lib stitched into it ?

During my possible checks of achieving this, I found people telling about "disassembling of the executable" as the only possible approach, which I am not sure of how to accomplish.

The whole purpose of this is for in-house application testing, so the re-linked app will never see app store.

Can anyone guide me to crack this use-case?

Comment: The short answer is: no, not really -- this isn't how statically linked code works. Your best bet is probably to include the test code in your application and have it conditionally disabled based on an info.plist setting. If the size of your test code makes this impractical, then two separate build targets is necessary.

Comment: Well, i understand what you say. But, in this scenario i will not have any access to the code-base. I would only get a .ipa / .app file which i have to modify for my needy.

Comment: you need to tell your employer that what they require is not reasonable. It is theoretically possible to make the replacement you desire through a _lot_ of manual effort (which would have to be repeated with every code change), but a) that would not be a valid test since you're testing significantly modified code, b) it would likely take more time than simply writing the entire application from scratch. Saying you have a legitimate test need and that you don't have source code to test raise a red flag.... something definitely smells bad in this situation.

Comment: But, i see few MAC applications doing this. To the application that i used, takes a .ipa file , perform few checks on it (is the ipa instrumented). If the check fails , they request for .p12 file and resulting would be a new instrumented executable. With the request on .p12 file i feel there is a real change in the resulting executable from what was earlier. I am eager to know how to have this made working, even without having a actual source codebase , so that i would use the same approach in Logging few messages at-least.